# "Overfull \hbox (11.58838pt too wide) in paragraph" but the line is empty

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzset

I get the message: "Overfull \hbox (11.58838pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 362--362"

It refers to the **empty** line between the newpage command and the example below, so I'm confused. Also, the tikzpicture is not compiled.
What am I doing wrong?
Thank you so much!

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl} % KOMA-Script article 

\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{langsci-unified.bst}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsthm, stmaryrd}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{ulem} 
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{document}

\newpage
 
\ex.
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{level distance=70pt, sibling distance=0.5pt}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center}}
    \Tree
    [. {\textsc{past}} [. $t$] 
        [. {$\lambda_1$ \\ example }]]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Please augment your code snippet so that it becomes minimally compilable, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: This is just a wild guess.  Was there a blank line or a `\par` before the `\newpage`?  If not, try putting one there.

Comment: You can also use `\overfullrule=1pt` to draw a line in the pdf at the offending spot: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/%5Coverfullrule

Comment: are you sure it is that file? (not references or table of contents)? make a small complete document that shows the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have tried adding \par and \overfullrule=1pt and they didn't work. It is that same file for sure. I edited and added begin & end document as well as all the packages, since I'm not really sure which ones are relevant... Thank you!

Comment: On my TL23 the MWE doesn't even compile, I get an error about `\@@label`

Comment: @daleif Yes, I have no idea what is going on. thank you

Comment: " since I'm not really sure which ones are relevant... Thank you! –" It s _much_ easier for you to test that than us as you have an example. Delete each package in turn, if the problem still shows, then post the example without that  package. Show the full log file for your example.